# Can a unit test not be automated?

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic

I know how this sounds..but today a teacher told us that unit tests should be automated. Should..How can I have a unit test which is not automated? I believe that the nature of unit test is, that it is repeatable. I mean, if it runs for the first time, it should run every time unless the code is broken. Or not? I am not a programmer (fresh student..).

Comment: I guess you could code a test that could be user/developer selectable to run.  Thinking of assert code, many times these are disabled for release type builds and therefore may not be "automated."  This might be an issue to take on "faith" for a bit until you get a bit more experience with your language of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have unit tests which are not automated.

For example, I have done unit testing on a method that parses text in a file, where the file was dropped into a directory that was monitored for these files. Before the test was run, I needed to manually make sure that the file was available in the monitored directory. Since there was manual work to be done, the test was not an automated one. However, the test could be considered a unit test because it tested a small part (unit) of my code. This test was useful for me, because although it would not have worked by itself, I could still repeat it every time I made a change to make sure the parsing was happening the way I wanted to.

Automating a test makes it a little easier for developers to test their code and keep it working.